# When adding rotations in unity the result doesnt appear to be the addition of the two rotations

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

i am rotating a world object, that world objects y rotation is 0.
When i rotate that object by -90 the objects y rotation is showing a rotation of 270.
Rotating that same object by 90(+) causes the objects y rotation to = 0
the code:

```
transform.Rotate (0, -90, 0)
transform.Rotate (0, 90, 0)
```

Can someone please explain the mechanics of this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you confused as to why a rotation of `-90` degrees results in a reported value of `270`? If so, they are equivalent values on the 360 degree circle. (90 counter-clockwise == 270 clockwise) Are you confused because the second line with `+90` rotation results in `0` degrees reported? If so, that's because the `.Rotate()` method is relative to the object's current rotation. (`0 - 90 + 90 == 0`)

Comment: What is your pivot point? One of the corners or the center of the object?

Comment: if you have a gameobject and rotate it by 'transform.Rotate (0, -90, 0)' when the gameobjects current rotation is 0 on the y-axis why does its rotation then = 270 @ChrisSinclair answered the question. also i was only referencing the quaternion and not the eulerangle so this added to my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually -90 degree equal to 270 degree but if you don't know about this things,reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Its all about basic mathematics.

```
(-2) + 2 = 0
```

similarly

```
(-90) + 90 = 0
```

If you want to know about Transformations check [this](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/geometry/transformations/transformation-using-matrices).

If you want to know about Quaternions check [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quaternion.html).

Comment: yes basic mathmatics is not the issue. 360 being 0 as the starting rotation. 360 rotate left by 90 degress is 270 anything > than 270 = 0 and anything < than -270 is 0 with fixed left and right rotations of 90 degress. with the current starting y value's rotation being 0 a rotation to the left by 90 degrees = 270 that was my confusion.